# Dataset does not exist

Tags: python

I have been trying to open 372 datasets (aerosol) using nctoolkit for a couple of days now. I have followed some suggestions given to some people who faced similar challenge but they are not helping matters. The whole reason why I want to open with nctoolkit is that I want to regrid one dataset (precipitation) so that I can plot spatial correlation of aerosols and precipitation. Below is my code.

```
import netCDF4
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from scipy.stats import pearsonr 
import nctoolkit as nc

da = nc.open_data('/home/bernard/Desktop/FinalphdCodes/CorrelationData/precip.mon.mean.nc') # its running perfectly
ds = nc.open_data('/home/bernard/Desktop/FinalphdCodes/CorrelationData/MERRA2_*.nc4')# line which is not running
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_10207/790498178.py in <module>
----> 1 ds = nc.open_data('/home/bernard/Desktop/FinalphdCodes/CorrelationData/MERRA2_*.nc4')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nctoolkit/api.py in open_data(x, checks, **kwargs)
    538 
    539             else:
--> 540                 raise FileNotFoundError("Data set " + x + " does not exist!")
    541 
    542         if checks:

FileNotFoundError: Data set /home/bernard/Desktop/FinalphdCodes/CorrelationData/MERRA2_*.nc4 does not exist!
```

Your help/assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean ```*.nc``` and not ```*.nc4```?

Comment: @ewong the  data is in .nc4 format not .nc

Comment: Answer below will work for now. The development version should work with your code given, as I've just fixed the problem: https://github.com/pmlmodelling/nctoolkit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nctoolkit developer here. I've noticed the package does not currently handle wild cards properly for nc4 extensions. I will fix this shortly. For now, you should be able to solve the problem using glob:

```
import glob
ds = nc.open_data(glob.glob('/home/bernard/Desktop/FinalphdCodes/CorrelationData/MERRA2_*.nc4'))# line which is not running
```

Comment: Thanks @Robert Wilson for your response, the code is running without any error but unfortunately it ensembles zero file i.e. there is no variables after opening the data with glob.glob, see the following:  <nctoolkit.DataSet>: Files: 0 member ensemble Variables:

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this at my end. What does `glob.glob('/home/bernard/Desktop/FinalphdCodes/CorrelationData/MERRA2_*.nc4')` give you? You just need to provide a list of files to open_data, so just a find a way to do that. glob should work though